# Mysql in terminal and workbench can't see the same databases

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm using a Macbook Pro. I tried to setup for PHP. The server I'm using is MAMP. After I start MAMP, I can run localhost/phpmyadmin and MySQLWorkbench. But when I try to run mysql through Terminal, I can't connect to my database. I had to disconnect MAMP in order to access my database through Terminal. Then when I restart MAMP, it just connect to Apache Server instead of both Apache and MySQL Server. I figure the port is not 3306 when I run mysql through Terminal. I wonder if I could change the port to 3306 so I can make change to the database I make in the terminal with phpmyadmin. I searched the Internet but couldn't find a solution.

Just now, I couldn't run mysql in terminal. I'm so frustrated. Can somebody help?

---

Update: I just found out Macbook comes with built-in Apache and Mysql Server. I followed the instruction from below website to set it up and it works. Hope this can help those who has the same problem.

https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/

Comment: Did you assign permissions to whatever user you are using from the terminal? Typically, you'd end up with `'<user>'@'localhost'` given permissions. If you then attempt to connect with the same username from a different machine, you'd have to explicitly grant that connection as well (Using `CREATE USER '<user>'@'<terminal>' IDENTIFIED BY '<pass>'`, followed by `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO '<user>'@'<terminal>';`; as a syntax).

Comment: What is your error message, if any?

Comment: Thanks. I'm using root as user. I reinstalled mysql. It seems mysql from terminal and workbench can sync. But there is a new problem. When I run MAMP, I can access localhost/phpmyadmin, but there's error when I run workbench or mysql from terminal.(Cannot Connect to Database Server)I had to stop MAMP and run mysql server from System Preference. And then workbench is fine while localhost/phpmyadmin. I tried to set up password in config.inc.php. It still couldn't run correctly. (This site can't be reached.) And the databases show in two system are not the same. It's like there are two servers.

Comment: When mysql run correctly, I tried to refresh localhost/phpmyadmin. And the error is mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe... I had the same problem with 2 versions of php (2 differents locations on disk). phpinfo() saw a version, the terminal saw another. The solution: change the $ PATH environment variable. 
Hope this helps...

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit? Thanks!

Comment: First check: is there only one installation of mysql on your computer ? I don't use Mamp. The version provided on the MySQL site is installed at /usr/local/mysql (in fact, a symbolic link to /usr/local/mysql-5.6.23-osx10.8-x86_64). Databases are located at /usr/local/mysql/data. Maybe MAMP installs another version of MySQL elsewhere ?

Comment: You are right. I installed mysql the second time with the latest version. Now I have two version of mysql. The reason I installed the second one was because at first if I wanted to run mysql from Terminal, I had to stop MAMP and start mysql server from System Preferences. But the database was not the same with phpmyadmin and workbench. The question is how I can remove the first version of mysql? Thanks!